# Remove the repetitive row by checking different column

Tags: postgresql

I have data sample such as below :

[image: set of data]

How can PostgreSQL eliminate the duplicate row by check column1 and column2 at different row ? I just doing a normal comparison but still unlucky at this time. Hope someone may share the idea.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: select * from table
where "to" > "from"

Comment: Thank you a_horse_with_no_name for the reminder . My apology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT d1.*
FROM distance d1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM distance d2
                  WHERE d1."from" = d2."to"
                    AND d1."to" = d2."from"
                    AND d2."from" < d2."to"
                 );
```

If there is a “duplicate”, this query will only pick the row where `"from" < "to"`.

Comment: Thank you. it is running. May I know how this . d2."from" < d2."to" ' ? working. Usually I use it for numeric

Comment: It is just to pick one of the two pairs. In this case I pick whe one with `"from" < "to"`. String ordering varies according to the collation, but the exact meaning is unimportant for this use case. All that counts is that either A < B or B <= A, but never both.